# How to use local aggregation methods in MapReduce programs such as in-mapper combiner?

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to implement a word length program that categorize words in 4 categories on large corpus by using local aggregation methods but I don't have deepest knowledge about how these methods work. Because I am so new in MapReduce field. For example what is the sharpest differences between combiner and in-mapper combiner? In addition I should add a combiner and in-mapper combiner to my code and should measure the differences between them. But I don't have any idea where I should start, if someone help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing an in-map combiner (as best-described [here](https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/the-in-mapper-combining-design-pattern-for-mapreduce-programming/)) is the process of writing code within the scope of a `map()` method which stores multiple key-value pairs and performs some kind of aggregation function before outputting. This is different from typical `map()` methods which tend to deal with only a single key-value pair at once. This is quite risky as the developer is required to be very careful with memory allocation.

In-map combiners are typically used for ranking lists - i.e. an `ArrayList` is used to store the `X` highest-scoring entries to the mapper, and are output once all key-value pairs have entered the mapper. There's obviously little risk of running out of memory (unless `X` or the key or value are very large), and so lots of data can be immediately discarded.

Alternately, regular combiners are basically reducers that are executed immediately after a map phase finishes, and on the same node. The advantage is that the developer doesn't have to worry about implementing their own groupings (unlike the in-map combiner), and therefore memory issues are less-likely. The main disadvantage is that you can't guarantee that a combiner will run.

Regular combiners are used often for things such as counts - the WordCount with a combiner (such as [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0) is the classic example.

For your case, I would always look to a regular combiner. Let it do all the work of grouping your categories, and avoid worrying about memory.